# Overide Core.js Options?

Tags: infopath, client-object-model, jquery

What is the best way to be able to manipulate objects in the DOM using JQuery/JavaScript, specifically in an InfoPath browser enabled form in SharePoint 2010?
If I try to grab a value from an input field or run code off of a click function I get nowhere. Grabbing values returns an undefined error.I'm looking for the least server intrusive way to gain access to the DOM elements.

after a weeks worth of research I've learned that overriding the core.js file is one of the  options. I'm not sure I have access rights to that file for starters. I'm using simple CEWP's to inject code into forms or pages. Below are the headers I use in every CEWP I throw into SharePoint.

From my basic understanding any code I run needs to start after core.js loads. If I can get past this hurdle I can get a lot more functionality out of my forms as we like to use infopath enabled forms. Any direction would be appreciated....

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink Name="MicrosoftAjax.js" runat="server" Defer="False" Localizable="false"/>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink Name="SP.core.js" runat="server" Defer="False" Localizable="false"/>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink Name="SP.js" runat="server" Defer="True" Localizable="false"/>
<SharePoint:FormDigest ID="MyFormDigest" runat="server"/>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.SPServices-2014.01.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either on of these lines was all I needed at the beginning of the script.....

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(HideWP, "sp.js");
```

or

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("FunctionName");
```